# How to calculate percent differences in a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `csv` file where rows `1-5` represent one state, `5-10` another, etc...  I also have a column with years `1970,1980,..,2010` repeated for each state.  In `R` (although I'm not opposed to a solution in Excel if that is easier), I want for each state to calculate the percent difference between that year and 1970, i.e. for `Alabama 1990` it would be `(AL 1990 - AL 1970)/(AL 1970)`, and add it to a new column in the data table so I can export it to a `csv`.

```
   State, Year, Num  
    AL,   1970,  1   
    AL,   1980,  2   
    AL,   1990,  3   
    AL,   2000,  4   
    AL,   2010,  6
```

**Output would be a column**

```
pct_change
0
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: Hi John, can you provide the data frame (or a small portion of it) so it can be cut and paste to load into our R sessions? Also, an example of what the output should look like.

Comment: @mysteRious Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dplyr` package includes the function `first` which provides an easy method for getting the first value of a group. So if we arrange by `Year` to make it so that 1970 will be the first value of each group, when we `group_by(State)`, we can use `first(Num)` to get that first value of `Num` which represents the value from 1970:

```
# Example data with 2 states

df <- structure(list(State = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "TX", 
"TX", "TX", "TX", "TX"), Year = c(1970L, 1980L, 1990L, 2000L, 
2010L, 1970L, 1980L, 1990L, 2000L, 2010L), Num = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
6, 5, 2, 10, 12, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(State, Year) %>%
    group_by(State) %>%
    mutate(perc_diff = 100 * (Num - first(Num))/first(Num))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   State [2]
   State  Year   Num perc_diff
   <chr> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 AL     1970     1         0
 2 AL     1980     2       100
 3 AL     1990     3       200
 4 AL     2000     4       300
 5 AL     2010     6       500
 6 TX     1970     5         0
 7 TX     1980     2       -60
 8 TX     1990    10       100
 9 TX     2000    12       140
10 TX     2010     6        20
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), `order` by 'State', 'Year' in the `i`, grouped by 'State', get the difference of the 'Num' with the `first` value of 'Num' and assign (`:=`) to create the 'perc_diff'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(State, Year), perc_diff := 
            100 * (Num - first(Num))/first(Num), State][]
#     State Year Num perc_diff
# 1:    AL 1970   1         0
# 2:    AL 1980   2       100
# 3:    AL 1990   3       200
# 4:    AL 2000   4       300
# 5:    AL 2010   6       500
# 6:    TX 1970   5         0
# 7:    TX 1980   2       -60
# 8:    TX 1990  10       100
# 9:    TX 2000  12       140
#10:    TX 2010   6        20
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
v1 <- with(df, ave(Num, State, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
df$perc_diff <-  with(df, 100 * (Num - v1)/v1)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(State = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "TX", 
 "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX"), Year = c(1970L, 1980L, 1990L, 2000L, 
 2010L, 1970L, 1980L, 1990L, 2000L, 2010L), Num = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
 6, 5, 2, 10, 12, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm getting NA for the entire column...  Also, sorry I think I was a little unclear in the question.  Each value I want to be the percent difference since 1970 so for each grouping I want to subtract and divide by the 1970 value.

Comment: @JohnSmith  Earlier, the example was not there.  I updated

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` solution using `tapply`

```
df <- df[with(df, order(State, Year)), ]
df$pct_change <- unlist( tapply(df$Num, df$State, function(x) 100 * (x - x[1]) / x[1]) )

> df
   State Year Num pct_change
1     AL 1970   1          0
2     AL 1980   2        100
3     AL 1990   3        200
4     AL 2000   4        300
5     AL 2010   6        500
6     TX 1970   5          0
7     TX 1980   2        -60
8     TX 1990  10        100
9     TX 2000  12        140
10    TX 2010   6         20
```