# How to Calculate the percent difference in a three dimensional array using R apply()

Tags: r, count

i would like to investigate a naive assumption by calculating the percent difference between cells in a three dimensional array with apply() in R. However, not getting the correct solution.

Located below is the percent difference that i would like to apply to each cell in the following HairEyeColor dataset in the "datasets" package.

the general expression for the the percent difference is such.

```
100%*(1-Female/Male)
```

library

```
library(vcd)
library(DescTools)

data("HairEyeColor",package="datasets") # load data

str(HairEyeColor) #show structure


a <- HairEyeColor[,,1] # male table
b <- HairEyeColor[,,2] # female table
```

bind the arrays together 1 for males and 2 for females.

```
HEC1=Abind(Male=a, Female=b, along=3)
```

output

```
, , Male

        Brown Blue Hazel Green
Black    32   11    10     3
Brown    53   50    25    15
Red      10   10     7     7
Blond     3   30     5     8

, , Female

        Brown Blue Hazel Green
Black    36    9     5     2
Brown    66   34    29    14
Red      16    7     7     7
Blond     4   64     5     8
```

A Contributor's note: The prop.table() command yields the percentages, calculated using the total cases as 100%. For conditional relative frequencies use the margin argument.
Using apply() then allows us to perform any calculation along any dimension or combination of dimensions in an array (or matrix).

```
apply(prop.table(HEC1), c(1,2), diff)
```

here is the output, however it is not the precent difference.

```
         Brown         Blue        Hazel        Green
Black 0.006756757 -0.003378378 -0.008445946 -0.001689189
Brown 0.021959459 -0.027027027  0.006756757 -0.001689189
Red   0.010135135 -0.005067568  0.000000000  0.000000000
Blond 0.001689189  0.057432432  0.000000000  0.000000000
```

i also tried this, with no success.

```
apply(prop.table(HEC1), c(1,1,2), diff)
```

here's is what one would expect for the percent difference between male vs female black and brown colors. It would be

```
(HEC1[1,1,1] - HEC1[1,1,2])*100/HEC1[1,1,1]
```

output

```
-12.5
```

desired table

```
       Brown    Blue       Hazel    Green
Black   -12.5    18.1        50      33.3
Brown   -24.5    32        -16     6.6
Red   -60     3           0       0
Blond   -33.3   -113.3      0         0
```

Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks

i researched this question ,however it is refering to time series in long format [How to calculate percent differences in a table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797958/how-to-calculate-percent-differences-in-a-table-in-r)

Comment: One problem is that `prop.table` computes proportions not percents so you need to multiply each table by 100.

Comment: @dcarlson -12.5 isn't equal to 0.675 %, for Black and Brown having men in the denominator.?

Comment: @dcarlson thank you for contributing. The following provided the desired table, however, is there a quicker solution?
>a<- HairEyeColor[,,1] # male table
>b <- HairEyeColor[,,2] # female table


> 100*(1-b/a)

Comment: This is the proportionate increase/decrease in females over males, not the difference in the proportions/percentages of males vs females. Since females exceed males in the sample, the expected value of the proportionate increase/decrease will be `100 *(1 - 313/279) = -12.18638`.  My solution provided the differences in the percentages of hair color/eye color combination between males and females.

Comment: @dcarlson Thank you, for responding. Is your procedure the same as using Delt(,type='arithmetic')*100?

Comment: If you are talking about the `Delt` function in the package `quantmod`, then no. That is for time series data. Your example is not a time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always provide reproducible data. Printouts can leave out important details regarding the structure. Use `dput(HEC1)` and copy the results into your question like this:

```
HEC1 <- structure(c(32L, 53L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 50L, 10L, 30L, 10L, 25L, 
7L, 5L, 3L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 36L, 66L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 34L, 7L, 64L, 
5L, 29L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 14L, 7L, 8L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond"), c("Brown", "Blue", "Hazel", 
    "Green"), c("Male", "Female")))
```

Now we need to be clear on what you are computing. Your desired percentage was based on the total number of brown-eyed, black haired individuals, but this is misleading since the sample sizes of males and females is not the same:

```
margin.table(HEC1, 3)
  Male Female 
   279    313
```

If instead we compute the tables separately and subtract them:

```
Male.pct <- prop.table(HEC1[, , 1]) * 100
round(Male.pct, 2)
#       Brown  Blue Hazel Green
# Black 11.47  3.94  3.58  1.08
# Brown 19.00 17.92  8.96  5.38
# Red    3.58  3.58  2.51  2.51
# Blond  1.08 10.75  1.79  2.87

Female.pct <- prop.table(HEC1[, , 2]) * 100
round(Female.pct, 2)
#       Brown  Blue Hazel Green
# Black 11.50  2.88  1.60  0.64
# Brown 21.09 10.86  9.27  4.47
# Red    5.11  2.24  2.24  2.24
# Blond  1.28 20.45  1.60  2.56

round(Male.pct - Female.pct, 2)
#       Brown  Blue Hazel Green
# Black -0.03  1.07  1.99  0.44
# Brown -2.09  7.06 -0.30  0.90
# Red   -1.53  1.35  0.27  0.27
# Blond -0.20 -9.69  0.19  0.31
```

Your original `apply` function computed the proportions a third way, over the entire array combining both tables. You should have used:

```
apply(prop.table(HEC1, 3), 1:2, diff) * 100
#            Brown      Blue      Hazel      Green
# Black 0.03206339 -1.067253 -1.9867853 -0.4362912
# Brown 2.08984621 -7.058527  0.3046022 -0.9035006
# Red   1.52759170 -1.347808 -0.2725388 -0.2725388
# Blond 0.20268645  9.694596 -0.1946706 -0.3114730
```

The `diff` function subtracts the second value from the first (Female - Male) so the negative signs are reversed compared to Male - Female above.