# Calculating percent difference from certain row based on multiple grouping variables in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple grouping variables. I am trying to get the percent difference of one type of "control" form, but keep the grouping variables. I keep getting an error.

```
percent_diff <- df %>%
  group_by(days,density,batch,form) %>%
  mutate(pct_diff = 100 * (value - value[form=="t25"]/value[form=="t25"]))
```

I keep getting an error that says:

> "Caused by error: ! pct_diff must be size 1, not 0."

The pct_diff column would be 0 for rows that have t25 as format, then whatever the difference is for the other two "forms".

Could someone please help me with this formula, while keeping all grouping variables intact? Thanks.

Here is some sample data:

```
value<-runif(n=36, min=50, max=100) 
days<-c("d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3") 

density<-c("1K","1K","1K","2K","2K","2K","1K","1K","1K","2K","2K","2K","1K","1K","1K","2K","2K","2K","1K","1K","1K","2K","2K","2K","1K","1K","1K","2K","2K","2K","1K","1K","1K","2K","2K","2K") 

form<-c("t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w","t25","6w","24w") 

batch<-c("r1","r1","r1","r1","r1","r1","r2","r2","r2","r2","r2","r2","r1","r1","r1","r1","r1","r1","r2","r2","r2","r2","r2","r2","r1","r1","r1","r1","r1","r1","r2","r2","r2","r2","r2","r2")

df<-data.frame(days,density,form,batch,value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you have provided isn't varied enought to have more than one observation in each group.

```r
> df %>%
+   group_by(days,density,batch,form) %>%
+   count()
# A tibble: 36 x 5
# Groups:   days, density, batch, form [36]
   days  density batch form      n
   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <int>
 1 d1    1K      r1    24w       1
 2 d1    1K      r1    6w        1
 3 d1    1K      r1    t25       1
 4 d1    1K      r2    24w       1
 5 d1    1K      r2    6w        1
 6 d1    1K      r2    t25       1
 7 d1    2K      r1    24w       1
 8 d1    2K      r1    6w        1
 9 d1    2K      r1    t25       1
10 d1    2K      r2    24w       1
# i 26 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

However, after seeing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797958/how-to-calculate-percent-differences-in-a-table-in-r) posted I think you might find success with `dplyr::first()`

```r
library(tibble)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
  
# sample data   
set.seed(16)  
sample_df <- tibble(
  days = as.character(sample(
    x = seq(1, 3, 1),
    size = 36,
    replace = TRUE
  )),
  density = as.character(sample(
    x = seq(1, 2, 1),
    size = 36,
    replace = TRUE
  )),
  form = sample(
    x = c("t25", "6w", "24w"),
    size = 36,
    replace = TRUE
  ),
  batch = as.character(sample(
    x = seq(1, 2, 1),
    size = 36,
    replace = TRUE
  )),
  value = runif(n=36, min=50, max=100),)

# solution uses dplyr::first
sample_df %>%
  group_by(days,density,batch,form) %>%
  mutate(
    pct_diff = 100 * (value - first(value)) / first(value)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    pct_diff = if_else(
      condition = form == "t25",
      true = 0,
      false = pct_diff
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 36 × 6
#> # Groups:   days, density, batch, form [21]
#>    days  density form  batch value pct_diff
#>    <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 1     1       6w    1      90.2    0    
#>  2 3     1       24w   2      67.0    0    
#>  3 3     2       t25   1      84.3    0    
#>  4 1     1       24w   2      72.4    0    
#>  5 3     1       24w   1      56.8    0    
#>  6 3     2       t25   1      72.0    0    
#>  7 2     2       t25   2      92.5    0    
#>  8 2     1       6w    2      89.8    0    
#>  9 3     1       t25   1      50.3    0    
#> 10 1     1       24w   2      72.5    0.192
#> # ℹ 26 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>